# Firefox is already running, but not responding

Tags: firefox, debian, thunderbird, firefox-profile

I am using two Icedove (Thunderbird) profiles. I am starting the profiles with following commands:

```
icedove -P "default" %u
icedove -P "test" -no-remote --class test %u
```

When I click on a link (URL) in the "default" Icedove (Thunderbird) profile, Iceweasel (Firefox) window opens, as I would expect.

However, when I click on a link (URL) in the "test" profile, I get following error:

[image]

**How can I fix this problem ?**

I am using Debian Wheezy

Comment: @Dave - yes, I am on Debian. But I don't think my problem is Debian-specific.

Comment: I used to have the same problem in my windows machine. But they fixed it in a new version, with a release note saying 'fixed firefox is .......not responding' . until then, i used to solve it by manually killing the Firefox process . may be this will be fixed in upcoming linux release

Comment: @vembutech - upgrading to the newest version is not an option. I am already at the latest version provided by my distribution (Debian), and I am not going to compile firefox from sources. Besides, you don't address the problem, but rather offer a vague and unconstructive comment, that could apply to 50% of all questions on stack exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

start thunderbird with the `--no-remote` option. From man `thunderbird`:

```
   --no-remote
          Don't connect to a running Thunderbird instance. Don't accept or send remote commands. This option can be necessary in conjunction to several of the options above, that won't have any effect when an Thunderbird instance is running unless -no-remote is used at the same time.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to kill all process id related to iceweasel and firefox and then give a fresh start

```
ps aux | grep iceweasel

ps aux | grep firefox
```

Get the Process_ID for both the process and kill it

```
kill  -9 <Process_ID>
```

Hope this helps!