# "Firefox is already running, but is not responding."

Tags: linux, firefox

On my Devuan GNU/Linux system, I have a newer version of Firefox installed, under `/opt/firefox` . I also have /usr/local/bin/firefox point to it, indirectly, via Debian's `alternatives` mechanism (i.e. via `/etc/alternatives/firefox`).

When I just start firefox and it's not already running - this works fine. But if it *is* already running, then startup takes a long time, and eventually I get that dreaded error message box:

> Firefox is already running, but is not responding. To use Firefox, you must first close the existing Firefox process, restart your device, or use a different profile.

Now, I don't have `_MOZ_NO_REMOTE` set; and I don't start firefox with a `-no-remote` option.

What can I do to prevent the above error (and thus allow opening links with a `firefox https://foo.bar/` command)?

Notes:

- Obviously, I don't want to close the existing running instance.
- Not a dupe of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1359648/firefox-is-already-running-but-is-not-responding-even-though-moz-no-remote-0), which has MOZ_NO_REMOTE set to 0.
- Not a dupe of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/851760/firefox-is-already-running-but-not-responding), which involves specific Thunderbird-Firefox interaction.
- Not a dupe of [this](https://superuser.com/q/78917/122798), as I don't seem to have any `parent.lock` file anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was some zombie running instances of the firefox-bin process. The surprising part is that the firefox may run in this situation without complaining, when no other window is open but when some processes are. I have no idea why the mechanisms for bailing out are not uniform, but that's how it is.

So, what I did was:

1. Close Firefox.
2. `pgrep firefox`
3. `kill` the processes you found, or `kill -KILL` them if they don't die.
4. Double-check for the presence of `parent.lock` under `~/.mozilla/firefox` (delete it if it's there).
5. Start firefox again.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

I ran into this problem myself, but none of the google results could solve my problem. Eventually I figured it out by myself.

---

#### Simple Version:

1. This environment variable was missing from my bash shell.
   `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1003/bus`

---

#### Exhaustive Version:

1. My shell is launched from crontab
   `*/2 * * * * /home/user/start-up.sh`
2. `start-up.sh` starts a `tmux` session.
   `tmux set -g default-shell /usr/bin/bash`
   `tmux new-window  -t "myservices" -d`
3. Using ssh to connect Console and attach to `tmux` session by
   `tmux a -dt myservices`
4. Launch the first firefox with profile name Proxy with SSH Console.
   `DISPLAY=:10.0 firefox --new-tab "about:blank" -P Proxy &`
5. Do step 4 again, causing the error, "Firefox is already running, but is not responding."
6. But if I do step 4 inside a Terminal rather than ssh console, firefox opens one more newtab as expected.
7. After cross comparing between the `env` of the Terminal and SSH Console, I found if I set this variable into the Console, firefox will do as it should.
   `export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1003/bus`

[Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECCs2.png)
[SSH Console after adding DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdOSb.png)

Comment: I also suspect the issue is DBus related, but the method you write not work for me.
I build firefox from source, maybe the dbus intergration is not built in? not likely though.

Comment: I fix the problem, it was a dbus issue. my dbus is not properly installed. `dbus-uuidgen` or `dbus-launch` complains .so linking problems. After I reinstall the dbus, the problem is solved.

Comment: Firefox has more problems on default Ubuntu 22.04. Using other browser is an option to consider. :(.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me, in Fedora (39):

dnf install dbus-x11

... I didn't have installed that package (dbus-x11, wich provides dbus-launch).

And without any  configuration or extra settings, I could launch "Firefox 'profile' -new-tab" without warnings.

PS : "Missing Twins" anwser give me the clue, sorry I dont have enough point to comment -\o/-

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I don't quite see how this answers the question.